# Fixing data truncation when using SQL aggregation function

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table:

```
avg_duration BIGINT UNSIGNED,
count BIGINT UNSIGNED
```

I am calculating the weighted average duration over many records like this: `SUM({avg_duration}*{count})/SUM({count})`. 
Problem is that when there are lots of records and big enough `count` values, the `SUM({avg_duration}*{count})` part gets too big and I get data truncation exception.
I thought about using `DOUBLE` for the column type instead of `BIGINT`.
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert to `DOUBLE` in your query rather than change the table definition e.g. `SUM((CONVERT(DOUBLE, avg_duration) * CONVERT(DOUBLE, count)) / SUM(CONVERT(DOUBLE, count))`

Comment: I'll check this. Definitely better than changing the table definition. I'm still looking for something a little less brute-force. But if I don't get any better answer soon I will accept yours. Thanks